# Why is the word "war" in Romance languages predominantly of Germanic origin instead of Latin?

Tags: historical-linguistics, etymology, latin, romance-languages

I wonder why in all Romance languages the word "war" ("guerra", with their multiple intonations) is a term that comes from Germanic languages, and that no modern language resembles the Latin "bellum". In English it actually came from Old French, which in turn came from Frankish.

It seems to me particularly curious since "war" is a term so significant for Latin tradition, and also the contrary, "peace", is inherited in almost intact form in all Romance languages and even in English from the Latin "pax".

Comment: The Romanian război is a loan from Slavic. I say this because you ask about "all Romance languages".

Comment: And Aromanian polim is from Greek.

Comment: I posit without a shred of Googling or etymonline consultation that "belligerence" comes from "bellum".

Comment: @Kaz. That is a good point. Romance languages do have more or less formal derivatives of bellum, but lack a reflex of the simplex.

Comment: We do have bellicose.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

A why-question is almost unanswerable, the answer is "because it happened so". But there was a strong trigger for the replacement of *bellum*, namely the homophony with the word for "beautiful", in Latin *bellus, bella, bellum*. So for the stem *bell-* the meaning "beautiful" won over "war", and the word for war was replaced with a borrowing from Germanic or, as in the case of Romanian, other languages.

Comment: The OED supports this theory, saying the Romance-speaking people "were obliged to avoid the Latin bellum on account of its formal coincidence with bello- beautiful" (the entry is dated 1921).

Comment: The Romans were a very warlike people. I can easily imagine that they regarded "war" as "beautiful".

Comment: Why are the words homophones in Latin?

Comment: They are homophones because they have the same spelling and there are no other hints that they aren't homophones. But they have different etymologies and were different in earlier stages of the Italic languages.

Comment: How much regarding these "earlier stages" is known or just speculation? (Would it be more correct to start a new question instead? I'm a newbie to this project.)

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica; Actually, there are reputable scholars (e.g. de Vaan) who believe  that bellus "beautiful" and bellum "war" are etymologically the same word.

Comment: @posfan12: Asking this as a separate question is a good idea. And there is [latin.se] dedicated to the Latin language.

Comment: @fdb: I quickchecked with wiktionary that gives different etymolgies. Interestingly, for both words the initial b- comes from an earlier du- /dw/.

Comment: If you celebrate war, you're thinking with your cerebellum, not your cerebrum.

Comment: Maybe some Roman guy said _Bellum bellum est_ at some point...

Answer (score 18):

The basic meaning of the Germanic **wirr* is “disorder, chaos” etc. The shift in meaning to “warfare” originated in Frankish and is attested since the 9th century in High German, English, but not Frankish, spreading to French and then to other Romance languages. So this really has nothing to do with Roman soldiers. It bears witness to the fact that in the Frankish kingdom Latin was the language of religion and administration, but Frankish was the language of the army.

Comment: Well, after the collapse of the Roman empire the fighting stopped being an orderly organized affair -- bellum! -- and instead became an ugly threshing about.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica. I think that is a very dubious statement. Unlike the Romans, the armies in mediaeval Europe did not usually slaughter and enslave non-combatants. It was  mainly army against army.

Comment: german has "Kriegswirren", a tautology then. "Wirren" alone is still found in contemporary news, as a weaker synonym of war, or unrest.

Comment: @fdb: I think you may have a rose-tinted view of medieval Europe's warfare; [the idea of chivalry came late in the medieval period, and it was always more aspirational than actually followed in practice](https://www.history.com/news/chivalry-knights-middle-ages). Actual warfare involved laying waste to the countryside. Admittedly, slavery did decline over that period, but I'm not sure "We burned your town, raped your women, and killed whoever didn't run fast enough, leaving the rest to die of hunger since we also stole your food stores" is a huge improvement.

Comment: @vectory whilst I agree that the original answer is not high quality, editing it to add irrelevant nonsense about modern French stereotypes only makes it worse

Answer (score 8):

My Latin book in high school contained the theory that *bellum* referred to the well disciplined style practiced by the roman legions, while *warra* was the less disciplined fighting style adopted by the german tribes.

With the fall of the empire, *warra* was the mainly adopted style, and thus also the word took over across the former territories of the empire.

Comment: Could this also explain why the period after the US Civil War is called "antebellum"? Did they consider this an "orderly" war?

Comment: @Barmar, the war happened in the waning years of the Neoclassical period, when the elites of the US and Britain borrowed heavily from Latin and Greek for all kinds of cultural references and neologisms. According to Merriam Webster the term was coined in the 1840s and later applied to the pre-Civil War period. I'm guessing that the style of the war was not relevant, but rather the people likely to use the term were of the social and academic classes that would esteem Latin over Anglo-Saxon terms. Further speculation may lead us into the murky waters of white supremacy tied to Neoclassicism.